# Failed to create function: Syntax error at or near "*"

Tags: postgresql, function, triggers, supabase, supabase-database

I am trying to create a trigger in Supabase with the following code that will help me update a certain value in another table. Following is the trigger code for the supabase function

```
BEGIN
  DECLARE num integer;
  SELECT count(*) into num FROM chapters
  WHERE seriesid=new.seriesid;

  INSERT INTO public.series(chapcount);
  WHERE id=new.seriesid;
  values(num);
  RETURN new;

END;
```

However, I get the following error `Failed to create function: Syntax error at or near "*"`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are multiple errors [as you can see in the manual](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/plpgsql.html)

The `DECLARE` section goes *before* the BEGIN.

And as [documented in the manual](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-insert.html) the INSERT statement has no WHERE clause.

So assuming you have the rest of the function (or procedure) right (which you didn't show us, the PL/pgSQL block needs to look like this:

```
DECLARE
  num integer;
BEGIN
  SELECT count(*) 
    into num 
  FROM chapters
  WHERE seriesid = new.seriesid;

  INSERT INTO public.series(id, chapcount);
  values(new.seriesid, num);
  RETURN new;
END;
```

It's unclear to me what your intention with the INSERT statement is. If you are trying to change an *existing* row, you need an UPDATE  statement:

```
 UPDATE public.series
    SET chapcount = num
 WHERE id = new.seriesid;
```

Note that if the trigger is defined to be fired on the `series` table, then you don't need an UPDATE at all. Make it a `BEFORE` trigger and simply assign the new count:

```
new.chapcount := num;
return new;
```